# Bad looking URLs in Opencart v. 1.5.5.1

Tags: url, opencart

Today I got a strange looking URLs on site.

They all started to look like this one:

```
index.php?route=product/product&product_id=1096**#.UVwcJpOePhs**
```

In the part at the end **#.UVwcJpOePhs** characters 5 and 6 changes every time i reload the page. In this case **Jp** turns into something different.

Any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: Aren't You using some security hash? Did You installed some extensions recently?

Comment: I am not sure I know what security hash is. For the past few days we installed these extensions:
admin filter categories 2.0,
category_and_manufacturer_filter,
Product Filter by Category,
YM_ecommerce,
yandex-metrika,
admin product filter plus

Comment: I think it could be caused by one of these: `YM_ecommerce` or `yandex-metrika` - try uninstalling/disabling one at a time to see which one is causing the problems for real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the result of a bit of javascript which if I remember correctly is related to a facebook like button, or an add this bar (or something along those lines). Why this happens or is added I'm not sure, but it is certainly not beneficial to your URL's

Comment: it was the AddThis plugin. Thanks!